# XmlIDREF is not working

Tags: jaxb

using JAXB 2.2.5b, and having

```
@XmlSeeAlso({BeanView.class, ViewField.class, ViewPanel.class, ViewTab.class, ElementRef.class})
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class ViewElement {
   @XmlID
   @XmlAttribute
   public String getId() {      
        return id;
   }
}
@XmlRootElement(name="ref")
public class ElementRef extends ViewElement{        
    private ViewElement target;
    @XmlElement
    @XmlIDREF
    public ViewElement getTarget() {
        return target;
    }   
    public void setTarget(ViewElement target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
}
```

Many class extends the abstract ViewElement

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ViewField extends ViewElement{
}
@XmlRootElement
public class ViewPanel extends ViewElement{
}
```

in the XML the ElementRef target element is repeated instead of keeping only the id ref

```
<ref id="mvmCredit" >
    <target xsi:type="viewField" valueExpr="" row="0" ... all ViewField attributes >
    </target>
</ref>
```

and during the unmarchaling of the XML model the target is null (the restoration failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade to JAXB 2.2.7 fix the problem