# JAXB - Marshalling and Unmarshalling a Java child object

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, marshalling

I am using JAXB on some web service objects which then get marshalled into XML so that they can be sent to the UI. My issue is that my parent Java objects (Provider) contain child subobjects (Service). Two different Providers can share the same Service. In Java, this is one Service object, referenced by two Provider objects, but in XML it gets translated to something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <dlwmin:getProviders2Response xmlns:dlwmin="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <provider xsi:type="provider">
        <name>First Provider</name>
        <providerId>1</providerId>
        <service>
          <id>1</id>
          <serviceName>Abc</serviceName>
        </service>
      </provider>
      <provider xsi:type="provider">
        <name>Second Provider</name>
        <providerId>2</providerId>
        <service>
          <id>1</id>
          <serviceName>Abc</serviceName>
        </service>
      </provider>
    </dlwmin:getProviders2Response>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getProvidersResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <provider> 
          <name>First Provider</name>
          <providerId>1</providerId>
          <service>1</service>
        </provider>
        <provider> 
          <name>Second Provider</name>
          <providerId>2</providerId>
          <service>1</service>
        </provider>
        <service> 
          <id>1</id> 
          <serviceName>Abc<serviceName/>
        </service>
      </dlwmin:getProvidersResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Or maybe:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getProvidersResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://api.ws.hana.dhs.hawaii.gov/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <provider name="First Provider" providerId="1" service="1"/>
        <provider name="Second Provider" providerId="2" service="1"/>
        <service id="1" serviceName="Abc"/>
      </dlwmin:getProvidersResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Where the Service element comes directly from the Provider object (note: I do not want to use a wrapper object that has a list of Services and a list of Providers).

Is this possible using JAXB annotations or some other way? And when I receive the XML on the UI side, how do I unmarshal this back into a list of providers with services without creating duplicates of services that should be the same Java object?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: JAXB just maps (binds) XML to java classes. If the XML is different, and you have a matching Schema, you get matching Java classes. So, yeah, if you're in control of the XML / Schema / WSDL, you can make it look exactly the way *you* want.

Answer (score 0):

you need @XmlIdRef, here an exemple

[JAXB and Shared References: @XmlID and @XmlIDREF](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html)

and the @XmlSeeAlso

[XmlIDREF is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823594/xmlidref-is-not-working)
or
[JAXB and Inheritance](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-inheritance-eclipselink-moxy.html)

Comment: Thanks but I tried this already.  The problem with this is that it requires a wrapper object (in the example, that would be the Company class).  This doesn't work for me because I then have to split the providers and the services into two separate lists which I don't want to do